# How to set inner to full width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm developing collapsible tables, like outer and inner table for every row click.

My Code:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table outerTbl mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">SL No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Program Details</th>
            <th scope="col">Program Levels</th>
            <th scope="col">Program Start Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Program End Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Duration</th>
            <th scope="col">Start</th>
            <th scope="col">Cacel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#row1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="row1">View</th>
            <td>Stay Active & Win</td>
            <td>03</td>
            <td>03/12/2018</td>
            <td>03/02/2019</td>
            <td>5 Days, 240secs.</td>
            <td><img src="images/start.png"></td>
            <td><img src="images/cancel.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1" class="table collapse innerTbl text-center col-11">
            <td>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Program Details</th>
                            <th scope="col">Program Levels</th>      
                            <th scope="col">Progrma Duration</th>
                            <th scope="col">Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>               
                            <td>Power Up <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
                            <td>Level 1</td>
                            <td>240 secs</td>
                            <td>Play</td>              
                        </tr>
                        <tr>               
                            <td>Warriors <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
                            <td>Level 2</td>
                            <td>5 Days</td>
                            <td>Play</td>              
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#row2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="row2">View</th>
            <td>New Year Goals</td>
            <td>01</td>
            <td>01/01/2019</td>
            <td>01/02/2019</td>
            <td>5 Days, 240secs.</td>
            <td><img src="images/start.png"/></td>
            <td><img src="images/cancel.png"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2" class="table collapse innerTbl text-center col-11">  
            <td>
                <table >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Program Details</th>
                            <th scope="col">Program Levels</th>      
                            <th scope="col">Progrma Duration</th>
                            <th scope="col">Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>               
                            <td>Power Up <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
                            <td>Level 1</td>
                            <td>240 secs</td>
                            <td>Play</td>              
                        </tr>
                        <tr>               
                            <td>Warriors <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
                            <td>Level 2</td>
                            <td>5 Days</td>
                            <td>Play</td>              
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to put width:100% on every level between the actual table but did not help.
Tried Examples none of them worked:

```
table {
    width: 100%;       
}
```

and One of the tables has no 100% in width, added this line,

```
td > table { width:100%; }
```

Using Bootstrap v4.1
In for inner `table` `tr` `td` is not setting full width? How to set inner table to full width?

Comment: you have added "table" classes in some row, in your css you have to find them with ".table" instead of "table", if that's what you're searching?

Comment: in example if parent width is 50%, so for inner table 50% is full width, same scenario follow in your problem

Comment: Try spanning the parent td equal to the total number of columns in its parent table. your inner table will expand to full width.100% is relative to the parent, and if the parent td does not have 100% width then how can the inner table get that width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this would help you. Below is the code for your reference [codepen](https://codepen.io/vss_at_kavayah/pen/qgOOBZ)

```
<table class="table outerTbl mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">SL No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Program Details</th>
            <th scope="col">Program Levels</th>
            <th scope="col">Program Start Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Program End Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Duration</th>
            <th scope="col">Start</th>
            <th scope="col">Cacel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#row1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="row1">View</th>
            <td>Stay Active & Win</td>
            <td>03</td>
            <td>03/12/2018</td>
            <td>03/02/2019</td>
            <td>5 Days, 240secs.</td>
            <td><img src="images/start.png"></td>
            <td><img src="images/cancel.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1" class="table collapse innerTbl text-center col-11">
            <td colspan="8">
                <table width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Program Details</th>
                            <th scope="col">Program Levels</th>      
                            <th scope="col">Progrma Duration</th>
                            <th scope="col">Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>               
                            <td>Power Up <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
                            <td>Level 1</td>
                            <td>240 secs</td>
                            <td>Play</td>              
                        </tr>
                        <tr>               
                            <td>Warriors <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
                            <td>Level 2</td>
                            <td>5 Days</td>
                            <td>Play</td>              
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#row2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="row2">View</th>
            <td>New Year Goals</td>
            <td>01</td>
            <td>01/01/2019</td>
            <td>01/02/2019</td>
            <td>5 Days, 240secs.</td>
            <td><img src="images/start.png"/></td>
            <td><img src="images/cancel.png"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2" class="table collapse innerTbl text-center col-11">  
            <td>
                <table >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Program Details</th>
                            <th scope="col">Program Levels</th>      
                            <th scope="col">Progrma Duration</th>
                            <th scope="col">Status</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>               
                            <td>Power Up <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
                            <td>Level 1</td>
                            <td>240 secs</td>
                            <td>Play</td>              
                        </tr>
                        <tr>               
                            <td>Warriors <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
                            <td>Level 2</td>
                            <td>5 Days</td>
                            <td>Play</td>              
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `style="width: 100vw;"`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />

<table class="table outerTbl mb-0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">SL No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Program Details</th>
      <th scope="col">Program Levels</th>
      <th scope="col">Program Start Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Program End Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Total Duration</th>
      <th scope="col">Start</th>
      <th scope="col">Cacel</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="collapsed"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#row1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="row1">
        View </th>
      <td>Stay Active &amp; Win</td>
      <td>03</td>
      <td>03/12/2018</td>
      <td>03/02/2019</td>
      <td>5 Days, 240secs.</td>
      <td> <img src="images/start.png"/> </td>
      <td> <img src="images/cancel.png"/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1" class="table collapse innerTbl text-center col-11"><td>
      <table style="width: 100vw;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Program Details</th>
            <th scope="col">Program Levels</th>      
            <th scope="col">Progrma Duration</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>               
            <td>Power Up <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
            <td>Level 1</td>
            <td>240 secs</td>
            <td>Play</td>            
          </tr>
          <tr>               
            <td>Warriors <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
            <td>Level 2</td>
            <td>5 Days</td>
            <td>Play</td>            
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="collapsed"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#row2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="row2">View</th>
      <td>New Year Goals</td>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>01/01/2019</td>
      <td>01/02/2019</td>
      <td>5 Days, 240secs.</td>
      <td><img src="images/start.png"/></td>
      <td><img src="images/cancel.png"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2" class="table collapse innerTbl text-center col-11">   <td>
      <table style="width: 100vw;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Program Details</th>
            <th scope="col">Program Levels</th>      
            <th scope="col">Progrma Duration</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>               
            <td>Power Up <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
            <td>Level 1</td>
            <td>240 secs</td>
            <td>Play</td>            
          </tr>
          <tr>               
            <td>Warriors <img src="images/trophy.png"/></td>
            <td>Level 2</td>
            <td>5 Days</td>
            <td>Play</td>            
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```